# AI or not an AI

Tags: ai.artificial-intel

What truely classifies a AI? IN science fiction they are thes super smart programs that usually try taking over the world. In the programming world i hear about AI for enemies in games or stuff along those lines. Would a program that comprehends Natural language be considered a AI?

Comment: AI is the study of programming and modelling techniques inspired by attempts to mimic human intelligence.

Comment: why is it that everyone downvotes questions for AI

Comment: @RudyGruse: This site is for research-level questions in theoretical computer science; please see the [FAQ] for more information. I think your question might be considered off-topic here. The problem is not that it is related to AI; the problem is that it does not seem to be a research-level question. This might also explain the downvotes. (Putting more effort in formulating the question – including checking the spelling more carefully – might also help to avoid downvotes.)

Comment: k but its just like i look down the list and see 20 questions all in the negatives for votes

Comment: @RudyGruse: I guess the main factor is simply that "artificial intelligence" is one of the terms that many people outside TCS are aware of, and hence we get fairly many non-TCS questions or non-research-level questions related to artificial intelligence. I do not think there is any systematic bias against artificial intelligence – for example, I do not work in AI, but I have some background knowledge of the field and I would be happy to read more about the latest developments and research challenges that are related to the theoretical aspects of AI.

Comment: ok then i understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, natural language processing is contained in AI.

[Russel and Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) start their book with some collected definitions of AI:

"[The automation of] activities that we associate with human thinking, activites such as decision-making, problem solving, learning..."

"The study of the computations that make it possible to perceive, reason, and act"

"The study of how to make computers do things at which, at the moment, people are better"

"AI...is concerned with intelligent behavior of artifacts"

This last definition seems to be the where most current efforts are, where you could replace "intelligence" with "rational" as in the economics sense of rational agent.